# In Xcode 8.2.1 I am unable to link @IBOutlet to the UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

I am having a huge problem when I follow this very simple procedure:

1. Create a new project
2. Add a label to the UI
3. Add '@IBOutlet var testLabel:UILabel!' to ViewController.swift
4. Open side-by-side editor
5. Drag from @IBOutlet to the label in the storyboard

At this point you should see two options in the semi-transparent window, testLabel and view however all I see is 'view'.

I recently updated Xcode from the app store and this is when the behavior started.  I tried on an older machine with Xcode 7 and the procedure is sound, Xcode 7 detects the Outlet.

Am I missing something here?  I tried installing 8.2.1 on a third machine and I am having the same exact problem.

Comment: Yes dragging from the open circle to the left of @IBOutlet to to the label in the storyboard via the side-by-side viewer (or any other means).  If I drag the other way I am not prompted with the options of IBAction or IBOutlet like you would normally expect.  Is it possible both of my downloads of Xcode are corrupted? This is driving me insane, and that's the only reason I'm here.  It's a very simple procedure. I will try 8.2.1 yet again on a third machine and try 8.2 and 8.1 on this machine.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get flaky Xcode behavior, it is prudent to empty the "derived data" folder:

- locate the derived data folder (it can be found under "Preferences" on "Xcode" menu and then choose the "Locations" tab);
- quit Xcode;
- empty the derived data folder; and
- restart Xcode.

If that doesn't do it, sometimes repeating the process but rebooting before restarting Xcode will do it too.

---

For what it's worth, while can't reproduce your specific problem, I do experience a related problem that if I manually write an `@IBAction` and then drag from an event for a button (e.g. "Touch up inside"), it won't always recognize my `@IBAction`. But if I drag to an empty portion of my code, and let IB create its own `@IBAction` and give it a name (which can be identical to my manually written `@IBAction`) and then delete it's templated @IBAction, it then recognizes mine, fine. There's definitely a little flakiness in this connection process.